# Java JPA Query with two Parameters

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm working with Java and the Spring Framework, and with hibernate. I wrote an Interface to get some inventory stuff by Querys, one for a Location, where the Inventory is and one for a ProductType:

```
    public interface ProductInventory extends Inventory<InventoryItem> {

      @Query("select i from InventoryItem i, ProductItem c where i.product = c and c.type = ?1")
      List<InventoryItem> findByProductType(ProductItem.ProductItem type);

      @Query("select i from InventoryItem i, ProductItem c where i.product = c and c.locationid = ?1")
      List<InventoryItem> findByProductLocation(long locationid);
    }
```

this is working perfect, but now i want to write an Query which selects the ProductType and the location:

```
     @Query("select i from InventoryItem i, ProductItem c where i.product = c and c.type = ?1 and c.locationid = ?1")
     List<InventoryItem> findByProductStandortAndType(ProductItem.ProductItemType type, long locationid);
```

but this isn't working. Maybe anyone can help me? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So why are you not using the second parameter in the query? You have "?1" for the first parameter twice.